# Fixed drop down Button HTML

Tags: html, css, list, drop-down-menu, drag

Hi i'm trying to create a drop down button.
my problem is whenever i hover to it the list just went up
what i want is for the position to stay fixed
and the other list appeared to the bottom side

here's my css

```
#Menu-Button {
font-family: MyriadWebPro;
color: #F93;
}
#Menu-Button ul {
list-style-type:none;
}
#Menu-Button ul li.item{
display:none;
}
#Menu-Button ul:hover .item{
display:block;
border:1px solid #F93;
background-color:#F60;
}
```

and my html looks like this

```
<ul>
        <li>Menu</li>
        <li class="item" id="Menu-Button">Roti</li>
        <li class="item" id="Menu-Button">Nasi</li>
        <li class="item" id="Menu-Button">Sayur</li>
        <li class="item" id="Menu-Button">Buah</li>
        <li class="item" id="Menu-Button">Sereal</li>
        <li class="item" id="Menu-Button">Oatmeal</li>
        <li class="item" id="Menu-Button">Telur</li>
    </ul>
```

can anyone tell me where my problem lies?

Comment: Your code does nothing because because IDs must be unique on the page and there is no ul within the first 'Menu-Button' to trigger a hover effect. You need to post enough code to reproduce your issue, and remove the duplicated ids.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...Something close...

```
<ul class="mb">
    <li>Menu</li>
    <li class="item " id="Men">Roti</li>
    <li class="item " id="Menu-Btton">Nasi</li>
    <li class="item " id="Menu-tton">Sayur</li>
    <li class="item " id="Mentton">Buah</li>
    <li class="item " id="Menu-Buttn">Sereal</li>
    <li class="item" id="Menu-Butto">Oatmeal</li>
    <li class="item" id="Menu-">Telur</li>
</ul>

 .mb {
font-family: MyriadWebPro;
color: #F93;
}
 .mb ul {
list-style-type:none;
} 

ul.mb li.item{
display:none;
}
ul.mb:hover .item{
display:block;
border:1px solid #F93;
background-color:#F60;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you cannot have duplicate id's in the same page, id's should be unique. So try removing the duplicate id. Please see the modified code below.

```
   .item{
           font-family: MyriadWebPro;
           color: #F93;
        }
   #Menu-Button ul {
          list-style-type:none;
           }
   #Menu-Button ul li.item{
         display:none;
           }
      #Menu-Button ul:hover li.item{
            display:block;
            border:1px solid #F93;
            background-color:#F60;
                 }

     <div id="Menu-Button">
      <ul>
         <li>Menu</li>
         <li class="item" >Roti</li>
         <li class="item" >Nasi</li>
         <li class="item" >Sayur</li>
         <li class="item" >Buah</li>
         <li class="item" >Sereal</li>
         <li class="item" >Oatmeal</li>
         <li class="item" >Telur</li>
     </ul>
<div>
```

I have just reused your code,removed the multiple id's and applied the id to the div,to match the css you have written.Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for the reply, i've tried your solution and the problem still there, whenever i hover to the menu it just "jump" after it shows the drop down menu like this http://i301.photobucket.com/albums/nn42/nara_ninjutsu/Untitled-5.png

Comment: This might be because styles of other elements might be making the menu to jump. Can't tell anything for sure until you could provide with more code or replicate the issue in a jsfiddle and show us.